# DNS records to point to another domain

Tags: redirect, dns, records

Usually I would upload a .htaccess to redirect a domain to another domain. But can something be done with the DNS settings when there is no hosting set up, to point one domain to another in a similar fashion to a redirect?

www.domainA.com -> www.domainB.com

Answer (score 1):

Your domain can just have a CNAME type, redirecting to your other domain.

Comment: I thought a CNAME type shows both domains with the same content instead of redirecting?

Comment: Yeah it does, but in the website now displaying you can just change the domain.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

One is to set up a virtual domainA server on the domainB box.

Another is to use a web forward in your domainA DNS record.